# Linux Serial Port Communications Timeouts - VirtualBox passthrough

Tags: linux, serial-port, virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box USB passthrough features to attach a serial port to Ubuntu (/dev/ttyUSB0). This port is used to communicate with a [3dm-gx2 IMU](http://www.microstrain.com/pdf/dcp/Inertia-Link-3DM-GX2-data-communications-protocol.pdf). The same port works with the vendor supplied Windows code where they set specifically send/receive buffers and timeouts. I can't get the serial port to function from Linux (Need it for deployment on an embedded system eventually). Is there a way to set the send/receive buffers etc. via the [termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) API?

Any Linux working code for the 3DM will be highly valued. Also any caveats concerning Vbox serial/usb so that I can consider switching to a real Linux install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceptable technique for timeouts is the VTIME property. The IMU works with VTIME setting of 10.